# Find string in col and copy adjacent values

Tags: excel

I need an excel function that searches through a column for the text "search" and then copies the adjacent value to another sheet.

Dummy problem:

```
A         B      C 

search   ...     1

search   ...    1.2

search   ...    1.9

search   ...    1.1

user     ...     1

user     ...     1

user     ...     1

search   ...     3
```

The function I need should search through col A and find all rows with the text "search" and then copy the values from col C to another sheet. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Have you tried `FIND()` or `SEARCH()`? Also, your formulas will need to be on the "other sheet" as excel can't copy a result to an empty cell without the use of VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following formula in any blank cell and it will find the word in column A and return the corresponding value for column C.

=VLOOKUP("search",A1:C8,3,FALSE)

If you need this value on another sheet, simply put this whole formula on another sheet and when you select the range (i.e. A1:C8) just toggle to the first sheet and select the range there. For example, if you put this formula on Sheet2 but the data is on Sheet1, the formula would be:

=VLOOKUP("search",**Sheet1!A1:C8**,3,FALSE)

If you are doing this in VBA, put this line in your code and lookupResult will hold the result. That can then be copied to any cell on any sheet you want:

lookupResult = WorksheetFunction.VLookup("search", ActiveSheet.Range("A1:c8"), 3, False)